# Using the HTML.DropDownList helper with view model and Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to use a html.dropDownList helper with a strongly typed view model with ajax. I can't the post the code because of the nature of the project.

Here basically what I'm doing...

- loading a mvc view via a strongly type view model
- clicking a button which does an ajax post to a controller method
- using the TryUpdateModel to parse the view model
- processing the request
- rendering a parital view for the ajax request

According to the article listed below, the problem is that "ASP.NET MVC assumes that if you’re rendering a View in response to an HTTP POST, and you’re using the Html Helpers, then you are most likely to be 'redisplaying a form' that has failed validation."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

Instead of "redisplaying the same form value", I need the html.dropDownList to be set to the same value in the view model.

Does anyone know of any custom dropDownList helpers or have any ideas of how to achieve this?

Things I've already tried/considered

- per the blog, manually removing the modelstate item...didn't work - didn't pick up the value in the view model - just defaulted to the first item in dropdown list
- considered just writing a regular select list...but this is sloppy and cumbersome since I'm rending multiple select lists in a loop
- writing my own custom dropDownList helper...wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its not fully clear to me what your problem exactly is, but I've had a similar problem. I used the Html.DropDownListFor(, SelectListItem[]) helper. At postback it sets the value to the choosen one. Your postback view doesn't require to have all the fields of the original model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, MyModels.DropDownSelectables());
```

Here I want the selected value as the model.SelectedValue variable and within my (seperate) model I made a array of selectlistitems. The rest is automagic.

Hope it helps, D

Comment: The project I'm working using MVC v2.0.50727, which doesn't have the Html.DropDownListFor method. The problem is that the value of the  html.dropDownList is not set to what's in the view model after the partialview is returned for the ajax request. @DerDee

Comment: Ok, I just ended up writing my own helper dropdown list extension.